# Problema com update na Trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger

Não consigo realizar o update na tabela devido a trigger o objetivo dela é armazenar as informações do registro alterado, com isso queria saber se o problema esta nas foreign key(FK), se nesse caso eu teria que criar um NEW.id para todas as FK.

Código da trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER  IF EXISTS trg_update_usuario;  
DELIMITER $$  
CREATE TRIGGER trg_update_usuario  
AFTER UPDATE ON usuario  
FOR EACH ROW   
BEGIN  
INSERT INTO auditoria_usuario(usuario_id_usuario,descricao,data_acao,usuario)
VALUES(NEW.id_usuario,'Alterado',NOW(),USER());  
END $$  
DELIMITER ;
```

Após o

```
UPDATE `dpu`.`usuario` SET `nome` = 'Guilherme Roberto' 
WHERE (`id_usuario` = '1') 
and (`contato_id_contato` = '1') 
and (`cargo_id_cargo` = '1') 
and (`endereco_id_endereco` = '1');
```

retorna o erro:

```
ERROR 1452: 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
     constraint fails  (`dpu`.`auditoria_usuario`, CONSTRAINT
     `fk_auditoria_usuario_usuario1` FOREIGN KEY (`usuario_id_usuario`,
     `usuario_contato_id_contato`, `usuario_cargo_id_cargo`,
     `usuario_endereco_id_endereco`))
```

Imagem descritiva da tabela auditoria.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: por favor, mostre o resultado do comando `show create table dpu.auditoria_usuario` para que possamos analisar melhor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os dados que você está inserindo na tabela `dpu.auditoria_usuario` são insuficientes, pois, essa tabela contém 5 **chaves primárias** (não podem deixar de ser informadas), sendo que 4 delas são **chaves estrangeiras** (a falta delas causa o erro que lhe é apresentado), e ainda tem mais 3 campos `NOT NULL` ou seja, você só conseguirá inserir registros se você informar dados para todos os campos da tabela `dpu.auditoria_usuario`.